# Trying to use typedef struct and struct arrays. Why am I getting a "segmentation fault"?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, parameter-passing, typedef

I am learning C in school and I am to make a program in class that takes in a file and stores information into an array of structures and use that array later on to determine if there is enough stock available. I have tried using the struct array globally and spent hours trying to pass it into the functions and declaring it in the main. However, I still get segmentation fault as an error and I don't know what my exact problem is.

```
typedef struct
{
    char        szStockNumber[7];           // Stock Number for a stock item
    long        lStockQty;                  // quantity in stock
    double      dUnitPrice;                 // price per unit of stock
    char        szStockName[31];            // name of the stock item
} Inventory;

#define MAX_INVENTORY 20;

void readWriteInventory(Inventory inventoryM[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char            *pszOrderFileName = NULL;
    char            *pszInventoryFileName = NULL;
    int             rc;


    Inventory inventoryM[MAX_INVENTORY];

    readWriteInventory(inventoryM);

    return 0;
}

   void readWriteInventory(Inventory inventoryM[])
{

int         iInventoryCnt = 0;                  // number of inventory items
char        szInputBuffer[100];
char        *pszGetsResult;
int         iScanfCnt;

fprintf(stdout, "%-6s %-8s %-10s %-30s\n", "Stock", "Quantity", "Unit Price", "Stock Name");

/* get inventory data until EOF
** fgets returns null when EOF is reached.
** store inventory in array
*/

pszGetsResult = fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pfileInventory);

int i;
for(i = 0; i < MAX_INVENTORY; i++)
{
    if (pszGetsResult != NULL)
    {
        iScanfCnt = sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%6s %8ld %10lf %30[^\n]"
            , inventoryM[i].szStockNumber
            , &inventoryM[i].lStockQty
            , &inventoryM[i].dUnitPrice
            , inventoryM[i].szStockName);

        // Check for bad input.  scanf returns the number of valid conversions
        if (iScanfCnt < 4)
            exitError(ERR_INVALID_INVENTORY_DATA, szInputBuffer);

        fprintf(stdout, "%6s %8ld %10.2lf %30s\n"
            , inventoryM[i].szStockNumber
            , inventoryM[i].lStockQty
            , inventoryM[i].dUnitPrice
            , inventoryM[i].szStockName);

        iInventoryCnt++;

        if(iInventoryCnt > MAX_INVENTORY)
            exitError(ERR_TOO_MANY_STOCK_ITEMS, szInputBuffer);

        pszGetsResult = fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pfileInventory);
    }
    else
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: A segmentation fault can occur when you attempt to write an array out of bounds.

Comment: What input data are you passing?

Comment: Can you show some sample input for the data file? Does the program print out any data at all before the segmentation fault?

Comment: Please don't delete the code from your post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb- what if you change:

```
if(iInventoryCnt > MAX_INVENTORY)
```

to

```
if(iInventoryCnt >= MAX_INVENTORY)
```

In this way, if `iInventoryCnt` is equal to 20, the program won't try to get into the 20th element of `InventoryM` (which is out-of-bounds, because 19 is the max).